# the continuity theorem with respect to Laplace transform

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, laplace-transform

> Let $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb{N}$, such that the Laplace transform $\phi_n(\lambda)=\int e^{-\lambda x}\mu_n(dx)$ converges pointwise to a limit $\phi(\lambda)=\int e^{-\lambda x}\mu(dx)$ for some probability measure $\mu$ and $\lambda$ in some non-empty interval $(a,b)$. Prove that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$.

Hint: Fix $\lambda_0\in(a,b)$ and rewrite $\phi_n$ as Laplace transform of the new probability measure $\eta_n(dx)=e^{-\lambda_0x}\frac{\mu_n(dx)}{\phi_n(\lambda_0)}$, with $\eta$ defined similarly. Show that $\eta_n$ is tight and converges weakly to $\eta$ and then deduce that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$.

This is the continuity theorem with respect to Laplace transform. I have found it in "An introduction to Probability" by Feller. But it doesn't provide proofs clearly. Does anyone see the proof of the the continuity theorem with respect to Laplace transform? Can you recommend me the source about this?

Comment: Which chapter/theorem is it in Feller's book?

Comment: Chapter XIII, Theorem 2 and Theorem 2(a).(Extended Continuity Theorem)

Comment: You can google to download this book. Thank you so much!!

Comment: But there the assumption is that $\phi_n(\lambda)$ converges for all $\lambda>a$ (and not only for $\lambda \in (a,b)$) - or am I missing something?

Comment: No. You don't miss something. I think proofs of these two are similar. My professor tell me this question can be proven by Markov 's inequality. I will try my best. If I can figure it out, I will post my answers.